# "Batch execution failed with HTTP status code: BadGateway. The response from the Machine Learning service at endpoint

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to schedule my AzureML experiment by Azure Data Factory (ADF).  After passing my job from azureML pipeline, I face with this issue "Batch execution failed with HTTP status code: BadGateway. The response from the Machine Learning service at endpoint https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/26c276f8420a4c30aae39b0c27845134/services/7b122129b2c041f9b4399d7e4b16e927/jobs/job_id/start was 'Internal error occurred."

Do you have any idea for solving this issue.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This looks like that an internal server error occurs when we submitting your request to AzureML web service. Is the endpoint here the one you put in your AzureML linked service? If so, the format seems not correct. Please refer to your AzureML web service portal to get the right Batch Request URL (https://services.azureml.net), which should be of the format like this one:
https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/26c276f8420a4c30aae39b0c27845134/services/7b122129b2c041f9b4399d7e4b16e927/jobs?api-version=2.0

Let me know if this helps.